# Autofac trigger lifetimescope creation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

Is there any way to cause the creation of a new `lifetimescope` when resolving a component?

Meaning something like

> container.registerType().As().TriggersNewScope()

Is there any other way of doing that? Other than taking dependency on `ILifetimeScope` and to directly resolve through it?

If there isn't, is there a way to abstract the `ILifetimeScope`? I don't want that part of the application to reference Autofac..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register your reused service as [InstancePerOwned](http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-owned).

The remaining unsolved part is avoiding reference to Autofac, here is a possible workaround:

- Define your IOwned interface in your Autofac agnostic assembly.
- Define and register open-generic CustomOwned implementation in Autofac aware composition root:

  ```
  class CustomOwned<T> : IOwned<T>, IDisposable
  {
      public T Value { get { return _owned.Value; } }
      public CustomOwned(Autofac.Owned<T> owned)
      {
          _owned = owned;
      }

     // IDisposable implementation and whatever additional stuff
  }
  ```
- Use IOwned instead of Owned in your types.

Comment: Taking this IOwned<> inside of a singleton will work as expected?

Comment: It better should be tested but I do not see why not.

Comment: It throws an exception saying the owner scope is not found

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your CustomOwned<T> was very helpful!! I finally managed to make it work!!!

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a "component triggers lifetime scope creation" thing as such. However, you may be interested in [`Owned<T>`](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#controlled-lifetime-owned-b). That causes a component to be resolved in its own little lifetime.

Comment: Sounds exactly like the thing I'm looking for. Taking an Owned<> instance in a singleton will create a nested scope from the root? Any way to achieve the same thing without referencing Autofac from this assembly?